# Loop through csv rows and check for a specific value

Tags: python, csv

Hello I got a question regarding loops. The situation now is that I got a csv file where I check whether in column3 (row[2]) the value "1" is present. If not just skip it and loop again with add up value:

```
i = 1
maxuserid = 7255

result_liked = []
with open('source/to/file/user_id%i.csv' %i,'r') as fin:
    for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t'):
        if int(row[2]) >= 1:
            result_liked.append(row)
            i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
#more code
```

The thing is that I need a for loop that runs all the code and after the run is completed add the value "1" up to my **i** variable.

The goal of my code is to run the whole code and after it is done I want to add up the value i from 1 to 2 and run the loop again, untill the maxuserid of 7255 is reached. How can I get a loop that does this from 1 till 7255?

---

**EDIT:**

```
import csv


maxuserid = 7255
result_liked = []    
for i in range(maxuserid):

    with open('source/to/file/user_id%i.csv' %(i+1),'r') as fin:
        for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t'):
            if int(row[2]) >= 1:
                result_liked.append(row)

    training_data = result_liked[:2]
    test_data = result_liked[2:]

    training_data_bookid = [el[1] for el in training_data]
    test_data_bookid = [el[1] for el in test_data]

    #training_data_bookid_int = map(int, training_data_bookid) #python2
    training_data_bookid_int = list(map(int, training_data_bookid)) #python3
    test_data_bookid_int = list(map(int, test_data_bookid)) #python3

    books_list = []
    for j in range(0,2):
        with open('source/to/file/output_new.csv', 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for row in reader:
                get_book_id = training_data_bookid_int[j]
                if get_book_id == int(row[0]):
                    books_list.append([row[2],row[1]])

    b = sorted(books_list, reverse=True, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))
    c = [el[1] for el in b]

    c_int = list(map(int, c))

    check_training_vs_test = set(c_int) & set(test_data_bookid_int)        

    with open("result.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write("Userid: %i || Liked: %s || Test: %f" % (i, len(test_data), len(check_training_vs_test)))
```

Comment: You can terminate the loop with an `if i >= maxuserid: break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
maxuserid = 7255
result_liked = []
for i in range(maxuserid): # this loop iterates through all users files
    with open('source/to/file/user_id%d.csv' % (i+1),'r') as fin:
        for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t'):
            if int(row[2]) >= 1:
                result_liked.append(row)
```

**Update**

I think you need something like:

```
maxuserid = 7255
for i in range(maxuserid):
    result_liked = [] # form a separate list for each csv file
    with open('source/to/file/user_id%i.csv' %(i+1),'r') as fin:
        for row in csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t'):
            if int(row[2]) >= 1:
                result_liked.append(row)

    if len(result_liked) < 3: # if list too few elements just go to next file
        continue
    training_data = result_liked[:2]
    test_data = result_liked[2:]
    ...
```

Comment: But what if the value for example, of user_id3 is all 0. Then the loop will break right? How do I solve that?

Comment: @Rotan075 No. If all values in some file is 0 then data from this file simply will not be appended to result_liked.Next will be processed next file (user_id4 in this case). The result is a list of all the rows where `row[2] >= 1` from all files user_id1.csv ... user_id7255.csv

Comment: Yep the code of you works. But I got a problem. The remaining code (which is not included in my question) requires that `result_liked = []`, is filled. But within my user_id3 the check of `row[2] >= 1` will fail and therefore my code breaks. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: @Rotan075 What we should do if `result_liked` is empty? Go to next file?

Comment: Exactly just, skip the rest of the code and go to the next file.

Comment: I see your update thanks! but that does not work right? If you appending data to a list then the list will always be filled when it  reaches a file with 0. right?

Comment: @Rotan075 In my code I use separate list for each file. In this case it will works fine. You need one list for all files?

Comment: I see, but whenever I run the code after the second loop I got the error: `if int(row[2]) >= 1:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Rotan075 Looks like `row` contains less then 3 elements. Could you check structure of file, on which you gets this error? And add line `print len(row)` before `if int(row[2]) >= 1: `

Comment: ah yeah I see, in the file there is an empty row! Damnit! I can fix that within the csv file but do you perhaps now a fast way to ignore empty rows? (sorry for all the questions)

Comment: @Rotan075 Replace `if int(row[2]) >= 1:` with `if len(row) > 2 and int(row[2]) >= 1:`

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. it works perfectly thanks:)

Comment: @Rotan075 Glad to help you)